# How to force users to re-authenticate on specific pages?

Tags: 7, users

Is there any possibility to Re-Authenticate user especially on ***specific pages*** like we see in some websites?

**Background**: for some of the websites like banking sites, when you are initiated fund transfer it will ask you to re-authenticate your account. Main moto is here, user will be logged in a long back ago using "Remember me", so for visiting few pages I want to re-authenticate user.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to do, as I think I've never seen this before.

Comment: Hi there, for some of the websites like banking sites, when you are initiated fund transfer it will ask for re authenticate your account?

Main moto is here, user will be logged in a long back ago using "Remember me", so for visiting few pages I want to re-authenticate user..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this module suits to my requirement: [Protected Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_pages). Some details about it (from its project page):

> ... allows the administrator to secure any page in your website by password. You just need to go to configuration page of this module and add path, password. After that the added path will be password protected. This module also allows you to send the details of this protected page to multiple users by email.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout) module. Some details about it from its project page:

> ... provides a site administrator the ability to log users out after a specified time of inactivity.
>
> It is highly customisable and includes "site policies" by role to enforce logout.
>
> Features:
>
> - Different timeouts based on role.
> - Disabling of timeouts based on role.
> - Permission for users to set their own timeout.
> - Includes some JS mechanisms to keep uses logged in even if multiple tabs are open or if the user is working on a form for a long period of time.
> - Includes developer hooks to allow users to remain logged in depending on your own project specific requirements.
> - Optional integration with [Javascript Timer](http://drupal.org/project/jstimer).

If you limit your **specific pages** to be accessed only by "role", using this module should help. If needed using the available hooks to further refine its logic to meet your specific requirements.

Refer to the [article about Auto Logout](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-auto-logout) for some more details (and screenprints) about it.