# How to force a login on a specific page only?

Tags: users

I would like to create a page (with a specific url) which will always require/force the user to login with their credentials. This would need to work irrespective of whether they were already logged in or the permissions they have.

I have considered using one of the access modules such as Content Access, but the issue here is that if the user has already logged in previously, they will bypass the login screen. One way could be to use the Required Login module. But I am not sure how would I exclude all of the website except the one page? The only other option I can think of is to do this on content view via Rules. I have tried this, but there is a noticeable pause between when the page is loaded to when the logout begins; making this appear more like a hack as opposed to a streamlined solution.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, closed this as a dupe of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194044/how-to-force-users-to-re-authenticate-on-specific-pages but is slightly different.

Comment: Sure, I did read through the solutions to the linked question and they did not quite resolve the problem above. Thanks for reopening it.